# How do I output the HBMs that Fluent NHibernate Creates?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, hbm

I am trying to debug my fluent application and would like to see what the generated files look like.

What are the ways to view them?

Is there a way to export them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind!

.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.ExportTo("path"))

Comment: If you are using any user-defined conventions, the current version of FluentNHibernate (version 1.2) will not apply those conventions when using the .ExportTo() method which means you will end up with invalid mapping files. You can find a workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8481967/670028

Answer (score 1):

Also

.Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.ExportTo("path"))

:)